# How can I flush /delete the Finder clipboard in OS X 10.8.3 ? I always see 2 items when I paste from the clipboard

Tags: finder

How can I flush /delete the Finder clipboard in OS X 10.8.3 ?  I always have **2** items when I paste from the clipboard.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're exactly experiencing and provide some more information? Have you got any *clipboard enhancing* installed?

Comment: What two items? Even after you reboot?

Answer (score 2):

Try execute command: `pbcopy </dev/null`.

`pbcopy` and `pbpaste` are two commands that provide access to clipboard.
`pbcopy` will copy a string to the clipboard (overwriting the original content).

In this case you are copying an empty file. Since you can't pass a file but a string only, this "<" (a redirection) will redirect the file content to the pbcopy arguments.

Comment: Could you explain the solution a bit.

Comment: Is there a simple means to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I really must re-phrase my question for clarity, i.e.

Is there a way to keep the clipboard from pasting more than one copied item **?**

Comment: When I use the Finder PASTE command the last TWO (2) texts copied get pasted.

Comment: This has befuddled numerous AppleCare technicians and Genius Bar folks as well.  Try copying and pasting text to a field that renders the text as a series of bullets.  Without being able to view what was pasted there is no way to edit the text !

Comment: I had not understood the problem. I have never heard such a problem. I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: "Computer Voodoo"  No Mac Genius or Apple Care technician has a clue.